# ActionScript 3 Labels Bold

Tags: actionscript-3

I am dynamically adding labels to a form and I would like to set some of them to be bold. I can;t seem to find an easy way to make a label bold in ActionScript. It is very easy to do in MXML. I would think that it would simply be an attribute that is set. How do you make a label bold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... the easiest way I would do it would be using the htmlText property, eg:

```
label.htmlText = "<b> Hello </b>";
```